# How to pass multiple argument to a container

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have one docker image with default ENTRYPOINT as entrypoint.sh whose job is to execute another shell script passed as an argument to this entrypoint.sh.
Now I am using this image as initContainer for some container. I want to pass two arguments to this initContainer. Currently I am doing as below but it is not working.

```
initContainers:
 - name: init
   image: <image_name>
   args: ["agr1 agr2"]
```

Comment: use comma between the two agrs. Eg: `["arg1","arg2"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **comma** in between

```
containers:
  - name: command-demo-container
    image: debian
    command: ["printenv"]
    args: ["HOSTNAME", "KUBERNETES_PORT"]
```

Ref document : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/

Multiple argument example

```
initContainers:
  - name: init-myservice
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', "until nslookup myservice.$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace).svc.cluster.local; do echo waiting for myservice; sleep 2; done"]
```

Or **list**

```
containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    args:
    - sleep
    - "1000000"
```

Same way you can pass to the **CMD** & **Entrypoint**